# ToolkitScriptManager throws NullReferenceException during concurrent access to a page for the first time

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i'm developing a ASP.NET web application which uses the AjaxControlkit 3.0.30512.20315. I have a `ToolkitScriptManager` instance on my master page which has some `ScriptReferences` in the `CombineScripts` collection.
If i access my default page from 2 differenct clients after an `iisreset`, i get the following exception

```
[NullReferenceException: Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +143
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.set_Item(TKey key, TValue value) +11
   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.GetScriptCombineAttributes(Assembly assembly) +129
   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.IsScriptCombinable(ScriptEntry scriptEntry) +148
   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.OnResolveScriptReference(ScriptReferenceEventArgs e) +415
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts() +191
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +113
   System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e) +8698462
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1029
```

Using `.NET Reflector` i found out that the `GetScriptCombineAttributes`method access a `static dictionary`, which is `not protected against concurrent access`.
Either i have a race condition in my code or there is a bug in the `AjaxToolkit`.

Can anybody give me a hint on that one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: "Fixed with January 2013 Release of the Ajax Control Toolkit"

Answer (score 0):

This bug was first officially reported on the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit website on June 1 2010. The issue was closed as resolved on Jan 23 2013:

[http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26752](https://web.archive.org/web/20161111034008/http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26752)

Since it occurs within the Page portion of the ASP.NET pipeline, you could try overriding the OnPreRenderComplete method to implement a locking mechanism to block requests until the first one has completed successfully. Even the most light-weight implementation would impact every request, so you might choose to include it only on a login page or something (in a scenario where no other page would render anything since users weren't logged in). If the error is occurring all over your site the lock will probably wind up in a base class of every page.

Comment: "Even the most light-weight implementation would impact every request" -

Not significant though if you use double check locking.